# How to search on German/Dutch compound words in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

In germanic languages like German and Dutch words often stick together. For example, "quality control" becomes "Qualitätskontrolle" (de) or "kwaliteitscontrole" (nl).

How can I make Lucene search on such glued words independently? I.e. if I search on "qualität" or "kontrolle", I want "Qualitätskontrolle" to be found.

There seems to be a filter for this: [DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/compound/DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter.html). But how can I wire it up with DutchAnalyzer and GermanAnalyzer for indexing and searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own Analyzer to include a filter.

Subclass GermanAnalyzer for example or write one from scratch and include the DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter to the list of filters.